# SpringDataJPA @ManyToMany crud

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to insert a goods

with or without some categories already in database.

I have seen many similar problems and solution,seem like `CascadeType`?

Actually  I don't figure out .

here are two class  and test

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_goods")
@Data
public class Goods implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7781710173608724249L;
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "goodsid",strategy = "uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "goodsid")
    private String goodsId;

    private String goodsName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Set<GoodsCate> goodsCateSet;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_category",uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "cateName")})
@Getter
@Setter
public class GoodsCate implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8990216455436375344L;
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "goodscateid",strategy = "uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "goodscateid")
    private String cateId;

    private String cateName;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "goodsCateSet")
   private Set<Goods> goods;
}
```

```
@Test
void test(){

    Goods goods = new Goods();
    goods.setGoodsName("apple");

    GoodsCate food = new GoodsCate();
    food.setCateName("food");
    GoodsCate fooddb= goodsCateRepo.findGoodsCateByCateName(food.getCateName());
    if(fooddb!=null){
        food=fooddb;
    }
    GoodsCate vegetable= new GoodsCate();
    vegetable.setCateName("vegetable");
    GoodsCate vegetabledb = goodsCateRepo.findGoodsCateByCateName(vegetable.getCateName());
    if(vegetabledb!=null){
        vegetable = vegetabledb;
    }
    Set<GoodsCate> goodsCates = Sets.newSet(food, vegetable);


     goods.set(goodsCates);
     // goodsRepo is a interface extends jpaReposity
     goodsRepo.save(goods);

}
```

it throws

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist:com.xx.xxx.GoodsCate

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't linked your category to goods.

I would suggest to add two utility methods (e.g. `addCategory(Category category)` in Goods and `addGood(Goods good)` in Category) which are used to synchronize both sides of the bidirectional association. You should always provide these methods whenever you are working with a bidirectional association as, otherwise, you risk very subtle state propagation issues.

In `Goods`

```
public void addCategory(Category category) {
        categories.add(category);
        category.getGoods().add(this);
    }
```

In `Category`

```
public void addGood(Good good) {
        goods.add(good);
        good.getCategory().add(this);
    }
```

`Note`: Also don't forget to add `remove` utility just like above one.

Then you can use below code

```
@Test
    void test(){

        Goods goods = new Goods();
        goods.setGoodsName("apple");

        GoodsCate food = new GoodsCate();
        food.setCateName("food");
        GoodsCate fooddb= goodsCateRepo.findGoodsCateByCateName(food.getCateName());
        if(fooddb!=null){
            food=fooddb;
        }
        GoodsCate vegetable= new GoodsCate();
        vegetable.setCateName("vegetable");
        GoodsCate vegetabledb = goodsCateRepo.findGoodsCateByCateName(vegetable.getCateName());
        if(vegetabledb!=null){
            vegetable = vegetabledb;
        } 
        //********After adding mentioned utilites********    
         goods.addCategory(food);
         goods.addCategory(vegetable);
         // goodsRepo is a interface extends jpaReposity
         goodsRepo.save(goods);

    }
```

[One of the article for Many to Many best practices](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)